# How to make a haskell module using EclipseFP?

Tags: eclipse, haskell, eclipse-fp

This may be a dumb question, but I am having trouble creating a haskell module in eclipsefp. I can open the HaskellModule wizard but if I click browse next to source folder there is nothing except my project. My project has folders on it but they do not appear on the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what source folders are in the Cabal file for your project. By default this may be the root folder, this is why you only see your project. In the cabal file say that your source folders are some of your sub folders and you should see them available in the wizard.
Bu default a new EclipseFP project uses src as a source folder, not the root.